# How do I implement a bit array?

Tags: c, arrays, bit

Current direction:

Start with and unsigned char which is 1 Byte on my system using sizeof.  Range is 0-255.
If length is the number of bits I need then elements is the number of elements (bytes) I need in my array.

```
constant unsigned int elements = length/8 + (length % y > 0 ? 1 : 0);  
unsigned char bit_arr[elements];
```

Now I add basic functionality such as set, unset, and test.  Where j is the bit per byte index, i is the byte index and h = bit index.  We have i = h / 8 and j = i % 8.

Psuedo-Code :

```
bit_arr[i] |= (1 << j); // Set 
bit_arr[i] &= ~(1 << j);  // Unset
if( bit_arr[i] & (1 << j) ) // Test
```

Comment: Avoid "pow". Use bit-shifting << and >> operators instead. (1 << i) == 2^i.

Comment: I did not know you can use bit shifting to do that. Thank you.

Comment: <pedantry>There's nothing that guarantees a byte == 8 bits.  It can differ per platform/CPU.  IIRC `CHAR_BITS` will tell you how many bits are in a `char` (which is the same as a byte in C, BTW -- it's defined as the smallest individually addressable unit of memory). </pedantry>

Comment: `if( bit_arr[i] &= pow(2,j) )` for the test is wrong, just use `&` not `&=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have a very good idea of what needs to be done.  Though instead of `pow(2, j)`, use `1 << j`.  You also need to change your `test` code.  You don't want the test to do an assignment to the array.

Answer (score 2):

`pow()` will give you floating-point values, which you don't want.  At all.  It might work for you, as you use powers of two, but it can get weird as `j` gets bigger.

You'd do a bit better to use `1 << j` instead.  Removes any chance of float weirdness, and it probably performs better, too.